# "Multipart request body is not present" when testing via Robot Framework using MockLab (wiremock)

Tags: robotframework, multipartform-data, wiremock

I posted this json file to a wiremock link created by mocklab UI using curl

`curl --data @post.json mocklab-link/__admin/mappings`

It returned:

```
  "id" : "d0478074-9dfe-406b-9ae0-e05527492536",
  "request" : {
    "urlPath" : "/path",
    "method" : "POST",
    "headers" : {
      "content-type" : {
        "contains" : "multipart"
      }
    },
    "multipartPatterns" : [ {
      "matchingType" : "ANY",
      "headers" : {
        "Content-Disposition" : {
          "contains" : "name=\"file\""
        },
        "Content-Type" : {
          "contains" : "application/json"
        }
      },
      "bodyPatterns" : [ {
        "equalToJson" : {
          "test" : "test"
        }
      } ]
    } ]
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 201
  },
  "uuid" : "d0478074-9dfe-406b-9ae0-e05527492536",
  "metadata" : {
    "mocklab" : {
      "created" : {
        "at" : "2020-07-13T20:19:37.992Z",
        "via" : "ADMIN_API"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, using Robot Framework, I tried to test that post method. I sent a post request with the right endpoint.

headers=

```
{u'Content-Type': u'multipart'}
```

files =

```
{'file': [u'file.json', '{"test":"test"}', u'application/json']}
```

However, the body returned with the following error:

```
                      Request was not matched
                      =======================

---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                    | Request                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  |
POST                              | POST
[path] /path                      | /path
                                  |
content-type [contains] :         | content-type: multipart
multipart                         |
                                  |
[Multipart request body]          |                            <<<<< [Multipart request body] is not present
                                  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I initially set headers as 'multipart/form-data' instead of 'multipart' but it returned a 500 code error and I also tried posting the file as 'data' instead of 'files', but still not working.

I am looking for any hint that could help solving the issue. Thank you!